# Correct use of API with threading in daemonized twisted

Tags: twisted, python-multithreading, twistd

I'm using a service whose API uses threading.Thread and I want to use Deferreds inside it.

If I run it like a standard python module I don't have any problem. Something like:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from outside import ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred

service = ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred()

reactor.listenTCP(port, protocol_factory)

service.start()

reactor.run()
```

While if I run the following .tac with *twistd -y* the service is simply not working:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from outside import ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred

service = ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred()

# Application set-up
application = service.Application("appName")
my_server = internet.TCPServer(port, protocol_factory)
my_server.setServiceParent(application)

service.start()
```

I think the problem in the second case is that the main reactor thread is not spawning the service threads itself, but then I don't see why (and if) it happens in the first case... I used callLater as a workaround -successfully:

```
from twisted.application import internet, service
from outside import ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred
from twisted.internet import reactor

service = ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred()

# Application set-up
application = service.Application("appName")
my_server = internet.TCPServer(port, protocol_factory)
my_server.setServiceParent(application)

reactor.callLater(1, service.start)
```

but I don't know if it's the correct way to tackle this. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please make a self-contained, minimal example: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Hi,

Please clone the example from here:
https://github.com/eigen-value/twisted_and_threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Github repo, this class misuses Twisted's threading API:

```
class ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        print "3rd party API service starting..."
        self.run_as_thread()

    def run_as_thread(self, *args, **kwargs):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_forever, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    def run_forever(self):
        while 1:
            print "Doing something remote..."
            time.sleep(1)
            now = time.time()
            if 1 > now % 5 >= 0:
                self.defer_activity()

    def defer_activity(self):
        threads.deferToThread(self._activity)
```

`ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred.run_forever` runs in a non-reactor thread.  It calls `defer_activity` which calls `threads.deferToThread`.  It is not allowed to call `threads.deferToThread` in a non-reactor thread.  There is approximately one Twisted API that it is safe to call in a non-reactor thread: `reactor.callFromThread` (it schedules a call to its argument to run in the reactor thread).

`working.tac` does the same thing but gets lucky and so appears to work on some versions of Twisted.  It is relying on undefined behavior that results from calling `threads.deferToThread` in a non-reactor thread interacting with how `callLater` is implemented.  There's no guarantee it works completely or that the behavior is portable across Twisted versions or platforms.

If you want to use the reactor's threadpool from a non-reactor thread, you need to write something like:

```
from twisted.internet.threads import (
    blockingCallFromThread,
    deferToThread,
)

d = blockingCallFromThread(reactor, lambda: deferToThread(self._activity))
```

However, you may not use any methods of `d` (the `Deferred` returned by `deferToThread`) in a non-reactor thread, either.

Most likely, if at all possible, you should rewrite the logic of `ServiceUsingThreadingAndDeferred` so that it is compatible with the reactor and then you can avoid all of these shennanigans.

Comment: Thank you Jean-Paul, that makes sense. Like I said, that class is using python standard threading and not Twisted threads module, making the 3rd party API not really "plug-n-play" inside the Twisted context.
It needs only to override the run_as_thread method anyway, so I'll try and follow your advice! Thank you